# How to check that file is opened by another process in Java?

Tags: java

I want to check that file is opened by another process. How can I implement such functionality?

In Windows I can write something like

```
try {
    openFileWriter(file);
    // File not locked => not opened by another process
} catch (IOException) { 
    // File is locked => opened by another process
}
```

In Linux I can use **lsof**.

But is there any **common** solution for both Linux and Windows?

Comment: Why your code wouldn't throw `IOException` in Linux?

Comment: Because condition `File not locked => not opened by another process` isn't true. You can edit file by multiple processes in Linux.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that. I can't help then good luck.

Comment: @FurkanYavuz Not a duplicate, that question is about checking if a file is locked, and the answers on that question focus on Windows. This question is about checking if a file is **opened** (which doesn't necessarily mean it's locked).

Comment: the answer looks like "no, not at the moment" (you will need platform dependent/checking code to implement this functionality (platform independent))....but it needs longer text to proof :)